# How do I make ajax data work on my php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, backend

I have typed the following and want it to transfer the data to a PHP variable in my PHP file. I have been looking at other posts for around 3 hours but I doesn't really alleviate anything considering my code is different to the original posters and I'm having trouble understanding it.

Here's the code for the java-script file I am working with...

```
    $(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/HelpMe/html/a.php',
        data: ({name_info:nameVal}),
        success: function(data) {
         // alert(data)
        }
      });
    });
```

*Note: the alert(data) is returning the text I want it to.*

---

And here is the PHP in my php file...

```
<?php
  $img1 = $_POST['name_info'];
  echo $img1;
?>
```

So again, I want the Ajax value sent over to the php file to be saved as a variable, but at the moment its just returning the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name_info in ****\mysite\html\a.php on line 2
```

Please note that I am extremely new to PHP and AJAX and don't have much back-end knowledge...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Button code...

```
  function generateURLfront_end() {
if($('#confirm-title').is(':checked') && $('#confirm-name').is(':checked') && $('#confirm-question').is(':checked')) {


  $(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'http://localhost/HelpMe/html/a.php',
          data: {name_info: nameVal},
          success: function(data) {
           alert(data)
          }
        });
      });
```

}

Button HTML...

```
          <button onclick="generateURLfront_end();" class="btn blue waves-effect waves-light z-depth-3" id="submit-but">Submit
            <i class="material-icons right">cloud</i>
          </button>
```

Returns the value I want...

[image]

Doesn't echo the variable that I thought was being set with the Ajax code...

[image]

EDIT: Tried the following on the instructions of the person who told me to use the click(function(e).

```
          $('submit-but').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost/HelpMe/html/a.php',
            data: {name_info:nameVal},
            success: function(data) {
             alert(data)
            }
        });
      })
```

Still doesn't echo my created variable on a.php. Just greeted with the the same error message...

EDIT: Someone just posted that it was my PHP and told me I should include the following to my php file..

```
    $inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$img1 = $inputJSON['name_info'];
```

Thats given me the errors...

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\Users\Trents\Desktop\XXAMP\htdocs\HelpMe\html\a.php on line 3
```

and

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'name_info' in C:\Users\Trents\Desktop\XXAMP\htdocs\HelpMe\html\a.php on line 3
```

is there anyway you could help me resolve these or give me some information on how to fix them? Thanks!

EDIT: Adding print_r($_POST); adds the line Array ()

Comment: use `data:{name_info:nameVal}`

Comment: Replace  data: ({name_info:nameVal}) with data: "name_info="+nameVal in ajax code.

Comment: I changed it to data: "name_info="+nameVal  but it still gives me that error, it isn't echoing the variable I thought it set it to. which is name_info.                            Another Note: I am running the ajax inside the a function of a button if that matters. So what I'm trying to do is set the javascript variable nameVal to a php variable if that makes sense

Comment: add how you call the function from button click. is the button added dynamically?

Comment: If you want to run ajax on button then call ajax on click of button event instead of  $(function(){.

Comment: removed the $function(){, returns same result

Comment: add event handler to button like `$('submit-but').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();//add ajax here})` some thing like this

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your question, you gets alert -> _**Note: the alert(data) is returning the text I want it to.**_, and yo don't get `echo` on the php page, right?

Comment: I am getting the correct data in my alert but on my http://localhost/HelpMe/html/a.php file, it's not echoing my (ajax created) variable, but someone just posted and deleted something that seems to have changed something. (shown with new edit) so if you can help with that I would appreciate it

Comment: @Felix that wont fix your error. can you do `print_r($_POST)` in your php file then put the result here?

Comment: adding print_r($_POST); into my php file adds another line saying 'Array()'

Comment: it means post is empty you are not sending any data . you have form? can you add the whole html mark up? @Felix

Comment: "it's not echoing my (ajax created) variable" You are getting correct data in alert because of echo and it is perfect. But you can't get data when you run php file directly. You will only get data with ajax's success function.

Comment: @Felix also you have error here `$('submit-but')` add `#` like `$('#submit-but')`

Comment: As I understand your Question, You are printing the `$_POST` data in your PHP file, you expect that echo to print the same data when you call the php file, but it won't. That's because you don't get the data printed, and it's not an weird.

Comment: So there is no way to extract a string (value) from an input via js and then send that string over to become a php variable without putting everything inside of a form? because I haven't done that (early mistake) and really don't want to rewrite my interface.

Comment: @Felix, No because js is client-side scripting and PHP is Server-side scripting, so you can't directly store js variable data to PHP variable.

Comment: Stupid question: have you actually set the value of `nameVal`? I don't see it being set anywhere.

Comment: yeah, i didn't include. Not that it matters,  I think i understand how to go about fixing my problem, just not the ideal option, but alg thanks for the help boys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Felix, No because js is client-side scripting and PHP is Server-side scripting, so you can't directly store js variable data to PHP variable.

What I was trying to do wasn't possible, but thanks for the help anyway!
I will just have to undo my mistake by rewriting some of the interface and I think I'll be good from there on.

thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Please try it may it's working.

```
$(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/HelpMe/html/a.php',
        data: {name_info: nameVal},
        success: function(data) {
         alert(data)
        }
      });
    });
```

OR

You can use jquery Post method for ajax request

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var val = nameVal;
        // button here
        $("#button").click(function(){
            $.post('http://localhost/laravel542/public/ajaxrequest',{ name_info : val},function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                alert(data);

            });

        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add brackets while sending data to php just send JSON.
e,g :

```
$(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/HelpMe/html/a.php',
        data: {name_info:nameVal},
        success: function(data) {
         // alert(data)
        }
      });
    });
```